# uploading image from gallery and camera to server

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to save the image that is taken from camera or image taken from gallery in kotlin. for now I've done this part and i'm finding other examples in kotlin but i'm unable to find. In other examples, images were send in multipart which was coded in java.

These are listeners

```
private val cameraRequest = 1888
private val pickImage = 100
private var imageUri: Uri? = null

takePhoto.setOnClickListener {
    val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, cameraRequest)
}

choosePicture.setOnClickListener {
    val gallery = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
    startActivityForResult(gallery, pickImage)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == cameraRequest) {
        val photo: Bitmap = data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
        takePhoto.setImageBitmap(photo)
    }

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == pickImage) {
        imageUri = data?.data
        if (imageUri != null) {
            choosePicture.setImageURI(imageUri)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Share the code you tried to send image as multipart.

Comment: i'm stuck to this part. i've not done anything till now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library for making a multipart request: https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service

Also, it will handle app behaviour for you which includes upload-retry on slow internet connection and many more.

Comment: can we send other parameters while uploading through this?

Comment: Yes, surely you can. Also, do check out the documentation. It is really simple and easy to understand.